# MySQL IF statement in left join

Tags: mysql, if-statement, left-join

I was hoping someone can help me.

I have the following query

> SELECT * FROM grids LEFT OUTER JOIN grid_images ON g_img_grid_id =
>   g_id && ((g_img_main IS NOT NULL) || (g_img_main IS NULL &&
>   g_img_width >= 475)) WHERE g_blog_id IS NOT NULL GROUP BY g_id ORDER
>   BY g_id DESC

It's not working how I want it to. What I want to happen is this. In the left join of grid_images I want to pick an image with g_img_main if there is one where it's not null, if they are null then I want it to pick an image based on a width greater than 474. so g_img_width >= 475.

Is there any way to do this?

To further explain i have two tables. One is "grids", the other is "grid_images". So each grid can have unlimited images in it. a grid has an id "g_id", and each image is attached to a "g_id"... so in "grid_images" "g_img_grid_id" tells me which grid the image belongs to. Some grids will have a main image marked out of all the images "g_img_main", some grids will not. In the left jin I want to choose the image marked as main"g_img_main" if there is one, and if not I just want to pick any image greater than a certain width "g_img_width".

```
== Table structure for table grids

|------
|Column|Type|Null|Default
|------
|//**g_id**//|int(11)|No|
|**g_permalink**|varchar(255)|No|
|g_type|tinyint(3)|No|3
|g_function|tinyint(3)|No|1
|g_format|tinyint(3)|No|1
|g_category|int(5)|No|
|g_name|varchar(255)|No|
|g_company_name|varchar(255)|Yes|NULL
|g_owner_id|int(11)|No|
|g_settings|text|No|
|g_about|text|No|
|g_website|varchar(2083)|No|
|g_donate_link|varchar(2083)|Yes|NULL
|g_donate_paypal|text|Yes|NULL
|g_image|varchar(255)|Yes|NULL
|g_view_permission|tinyint(1)|No|1
|g_post_permission|tinyint(1)|No|1
|g_allow_voting|tinyint(1)|Yes|NULL
|g_show_share|tinyint(4)|Yes|NULL
|g_site_grid|tinyint(1)|Yes|0
|g_date_created|int(11)|No|
|g_votes_per_user|int(11)|Yes|NULL
|g_votes_require_email|tinyint(1)|Yes|NULL
|g_facebook_eligible|tinyint(1)|Yes|NULL
|g_facebook_active|tinyint(1)|Yes|NULL
|g_facebook_app_tab_id|varchar(100)|Yes|NULL
|g_facebook_page_id|varchar(100)|Yes|NULL
|g_facebook_page_name|varchar(255)|Yes|NULL
|g_facebook_page_category|varchar(100)|Yes|NULL
|g_facebook_page_link|text|No|
|g_facebook_page_about|text|No|
|g_votes_rank_display|tinyint(1)|Yes|NULL
|g_lock_center|tinyint(1)|Yes|NULL
|g_passthe_item|varchar(255)|Yes|NULL
|g_facebook_img|varchar(255)|Yes|NULL
|g_pinterest_img|varchar(255)|Yes|NULL
|g_montage_img|varchar(255)|Yes|NULL
|g_views|int(11)|No|0
|g_blog_id|int(11)|Yes|NULL
== Dumping data for table grids

|------
|g_id|g_permalink|g_type|g_function|g_format|g_category|g_name|g_company_name|g_owner_id|g_settings|g_about|g_website|g_donate_link|g_donate_paypal|g_image|g_view_permission|g_post_permission|g_allow_voting|g_show_share|g_site_grid|g_date_created|g_votes_per_user|g_votes_require_email|g_facebook_eligible|g_facebook_active|g_facebook_app_tab_id|g_facebook_page_id|g_facebook_page_name|g_facebook_page_category|g_facebook_page_link|g_facebook_page_about|g_votes_rank_display|g_lock_center|g_passthe_item|g_facebook_img|g_pinterest_img|g_montage_img|g_views|g_blog_id
|------
|333|33-plus-ugliest-christmas-sweaters|1|1|4|0|33+ Ugliest Christmas Sweaters|NULL|11|null|&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;line-height: 22.3999996185303px;&quot;&gt;Just when you thought you've seen the ugliest Christmas sweaters around these people took ugly to the next level. Please feel free to share your comments, cuz some of these really need commenting...&lt;/span&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/p&gt;| | |NULL| |1|2|NULL|1|1|1416865122|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL| | |NULL|NULL|NULL|2014/11/26/14170476241649711529-4x3.jpg|2014/11/26/14170476241649711529pin-2x6.jpg|2014/11/26/14170476241649711529.jpg|0|20


== Table structure for table grid_images

|------
|Column|Type|Null|Default
|------
|//**g_img_id**//|int(11)|No|
|g_img_mem_id|int(11)|Yes|1
|g_img_dir|varchar(50)|No|
|g_img_file|varchar(100)|No|
|g_img_caption|text|Yes|NULL
|g_img_link|varchar(2083)|No|
|g_img_grid_id|int(11)|No|1
|g_img_date_added|int(11)|No|
|g_img_uploader_ip|int(11)|No|
|g_img_lat|decimal(18,12)|Yes|NULL
|g_img_lng|decimal(18,12)|Yes|NULL
|g_img_width|int(6)|Yes|NULL
|g_img_height|int(6)|Yes|NULL
|g_img_reported|tinyint(1)|Yes|NULL
|g_img_reported_access_code|varchar(100)|Yes|NULL
|g_img_last_edit|int(11)|Yes|NULL
|g_img_flickr_id|varchar(255)|No|
|g_img_facebook_id|varchar(255)|No|
|g_img_original_id|int(11)|Yes|NULL
|g_img_reposted_from|int(11)|Yes|NULL
|g_img_first_name|varchar(100)|Yes|NULL
|g_img_email|varchar(255)|Yes|NULL
|g_img_hearts|int(11)|No|0
|g_img_views|int(11)|No|0
|g_img_main|tinyint(1)|Yes|NULL
== Dumping data for table grid_images

|------
|g_img_id|g_img_mem_id|g_img_dir|g_img_file|g_img_caption|g_img_link|g_img_grid_id|g_img_date_added|g_img_uploader_ip|g_img_lat|g_img_lng|g_img_width|g_img_height|g_img_reported|g_img_reported_access_code|g_img_last_edit|g_img_flickr_id|g_img_facebook_id|g_img_original_id|g_img_reposted_from|g_img_first_name|g_img_email|g_img_hearts|g_img_views|g_img_main
|------
|15918|11|2014/11/22/|13793150131416692879.jpg| | |333|1416692879|849259821|NULL|NULL|453|768|NULL|NULL|NULL| | |NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|0|0|NULL
|15919|11|2014/11/22/|4655589171416692816.jpg| | |333|1416692816|849259821|NULL|NULL|613|768|NULL|NULL|NULL| | |NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|0|0|NULL
|15920|11|2014/11/22/|463211921416692661.jpg| | |333|1416692661|849259821|NULL|NULL|495|475|NULL|NULL|NULL| | |NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|0|0|NULL
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that from phpmyadmin?

Comment: Ok. added in table structures and some sample records

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. Is there at least one image for each grid?

Comment: Yes there is, always at least one

Answer (score 0):

Can you just put the condition in the `WHERE` part of your query?

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM grids 
LEFT OUTER JOIN grid_images 
ON g_img_grid_id = g_id 
WHERE g_blog_id IS NOT NULL 
AND (g_img_main IS NOT NULL OR (g_img_main IS NULL AND g_img_width >= 475)) 
GROUP BY g_id 
ORDER BY g_id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what the following query attempts: Get all the ids for which there is a master image, then union that with records for which there is no master record. That should give you a record for each grid...

```
-- Get the records with a master image. Assumes there is only one master per grid
SELECT g.g_id, i.g_img_id -- or whatever columns you need
FROM
grids g 
INNER JOIN
grid_images i on i.gm_img_grid_id = g.g_id
WHERE i.g_img_main IS NOT NULL AND g.g_blog_id IS NOT NULL

UNION
-- now get the the other records.

SELECT g.g_id,min(i.g_img_id) as g_img_id -- columns must match those in the first select
FROM grids g
INNER JOIN
grid_images i on i.gm_img_grid_id = g.g_id
WHERE i.g_img_main IS NULL 
AND g.g_blog_id IS NOT NULL
AND i.g_img_width >=475
GROUP BY g.g_id -- need to group by to get only one record per id
```